# Only show posts belonging to multiple cateogries at same time

Tags: posts, categories, customization

For blog post page, I have about 100 posts-categories. If I select 2 or 3 or more categories out of them randomly, for example category A and category B, I hope the blog page can only show posts belonging to A and B at same time.

The following code can only show posts belonging to random categories selected by admin under "or" condition. If I select 2 categories randomly, the blog page shows all the posts belonging to any of the selected categories.

```
$args = Array(
    'post_type'      => $post_type,
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => $ppp,
    'paged'          => $page
);
$posts = new WP_Query( $args );
```

How do I update the code to show posts belonging to all the selected post categories at same time?

Comment: Welcom to WPSE. Just a tip, if you add code to your question, highlight your code in the editor and click on the `{}` sigh above the editor, this will add your code in a code block and make it readable :-). To get you started, please visit [ask], [help] and take a [tour] to learn how the SE sites operate and how to get the maximum out of them. :-)

Answer (score 0):

To get posts that belongs to all selected categories, you can make use of the [`category__and`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters) parameter.

Example:

You can the following to your query arguments, this will only display posts that are in category 1 **AND** 2

```
'category__and' => array( 1, 2 ),
```